# Как переименовать колонки в df Pandas с нижним подчеркиванием

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'Первое имя': "AA", 'Второе имя': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'Первое имя': "BB", 'Второе имя': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'Первое имя': "AA", 'Второе имя': 2}])
```

Есть ли способ все названия столбцов где есть пробел переименовать в названия с _, то есть Первое_имя, например, вместо `Первое имя`. Колонок в разы больше поэтому в ручную не вариант.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Вариант 1:

```
a = a.rename(columns=lambda col: col.replace(" ", "_"))
```

#### Вариант 2:

```
a.columns = a.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")
```

#### Вариант 3:

```
a.columns = a.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "_"))
```

#### Результат:

```
In [8]: a
Out[8]:
   id  b Первое_имя  Второе_имя
0   1  2         AA           2
1   1  2         BB           2
2   1  4         AA           2
```